# Video output port not recognized (recent 22.04 update?)

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I run Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a fairly old Dell Laptop. It (normally) has four DP ports, DP-1 through DP-4, and the HDMI socket appears as DP-4. Recently I went to give a presentation and found that I could not get any output at all on HDMI. At the time, I assumed that my aging hardware had died. The VGA port worked fine, so we got by.

However, my wife has almost the same model laptop (one generation older) and she used her HDMI output for a presentation a week ago, but went to use it today, and it too would not generate any output. At this point I got suspicious and started more investigation, it was then that I noticed that the output of xrandr lists the internal display, the VGA port and an HDMI port (which isn't the actual HDMI port, never has been), and only DP-1, DP-2 through DP-4 aren't there. This reflects the behavior of the "settings" tool which simply doesn't show anything connected.

Then, I booted from an old Ubuntu 18.04 install disk, and the external screen (still connected as it was when 22.04 refused to recognize anything) pops into life perfectly well.

The fact that my wife's machine quit driving this port in the last week or so makes me think this is some kind of update issue (my machine was rebuilt from scratch much more recently than hers and I'm not sure I have tried to use the HDMI port at all since that fresh install of 22.04.3).

What do I need to report to help someone help me work out what's going on and find a work around and/or fix the problem in an update?

At a first guess at what might be helpful, this is the output of "hwinfo --gfxcard":

```
    13: PCI 100.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: VCu0.q87dynqFfH7
  Parent ID: vSkL.uHVYA+EuUr0
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "nVidia GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x0ff6 "GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1028 "Dell"
  SubDevice: pci 0x15cc 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Memory Range: 0xf4000000-0xf4ffffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  Memory Range: 0xe0000000-0xefffffff (ro,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  Memory Range: 0xf0000000-0xf1ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  I/O Ports: 0xe000-0xe07f (rw,disabled)
  Memory Range: 0xf5000000-0xf507ffff (ro,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 11 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd00000FF6sv00001028sd000015CCbc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nvidiafb is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidiafb"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nouveau is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #10 (PCI bridge)

26: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: _Znp.Ucbde_kbrc3
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Device Name: "Onboard IGD"
  Model: "Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x0416 "4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1028 "Dell"
  SubDevice: pci 0x05cc 
  Revision: 0x06
  Driver: "i915"
  Driver Modules: "i915"
  Memory Range: 0xf5400000-0xf57fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xf000-0xf03f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 37 (57500 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00000416sv00001028sd000005CCbc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: i915 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

Primary display adapter: #13
```

The machine is running the "recommended driver" which is nvidia-driver-390
And the machine itself is a Dell Precision M4800 (my wife's is an M4700 if memory serves, maybe M4600, but virtually identical packaging. If it's relevant I can of course dig out the exact model etc.)

Edits/additions:
$ uname -r
6.5.0-17-generic

I tried to change video driver, but got errors claiming I wasn't authorized (I am, I do know my password, I am an admin user, and I typed the password correctly). This is as much of the error report as I could grab (can't copy paste the text, and can't move the window)
[image: Error report...]

```
$ ls /bin/gcc*
/bin/gcc     /bin/gcc-ar     /bin/gcc-nm     /bin/gcc-ranlib
/bin/gcc-11  /bin/gcc-ar-11  /bin/gcc-nm-11  /bin/gcc-ranlib-11
/bin/gcc-12  /bin/gcc-ar-12  /bin/gcc-nm-12  /bin/gcc-ranlib-12

$ strings /lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko |grep gcc
strings: '/lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko': No such file

$ ls /lib/modules
5.15.0-25-generic  5.15.0-48-generic  5.19.0-38-generic  6.2.0-32-generic
5.15.0-30-generic  5.15.0-50-generic  5.19.0-40-generic  6.2.0-33-generic
5.15.0-33-generic  5.15.0-52-generic  5.19.0-41-generic  6.2.0-34-generic
5.15.0-37-generic  5.15.0-53-generic  5.19.0-42-generic  6.2.0-35-generic
5.15.0-39-generic  5.15.0-56-generic  5.19.0-43-generic  6.2.0-36-generic
5.15.0-40-generic  5.15.0-57-generic  5.19.0-45-generic  6.2.0-37-generic
5.15.0-41-generic  5.15.0-58-generic  5.19.0-46-generic  6.2.0-39-generic
5.15.0-43-generic  5.15.0-60-generic  5.19.0-50-generic  6.5.0-14-generic
5.15.0-46-generic  5.19.0-32-generic  6.2.0-26-generic   6.5.0-15-generic
5.15.0-47-generic  5.19.0-35-generic  6.2.0-31-generic   6.5.0-17-generic

$ find /lib/modules -name nvidia\*ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/nvidia-390/nvidia-modeset.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/nvidia-390/nvidia-uvm.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/nvidia-390/nvidia.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/nvidia-390/nvidia-drm.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia/nvidiafb.ko
/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/nvidia-wmi-ec-backlight.ko
/lib/modules/6.5.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia/nvidiafb.ko
/lib/modules/6.5.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/nvidia-wmi-ec-backlight.ko
/lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia/nvidiafb.ko
/lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/nvidia-wmi-ec-backlight.ko

$ ls /boot
config-6.2.0-39-generic      memtest86+.bin
config-6.5.0-15-generic      memtest86+.elf
config-6.5.0-17-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
efi                          System.map-6.2.0-39-generic
grub                         System.map-6.5.0-15-generic
initrd.img                   System.map-6.5.0-17-generic
initrd.img-6.2.0-39-generic  vmlinuz
initrd.img-6.5.0-15-generic  vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic
initrd.img-6.5.0-17-generic  vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic
initrd.img.old               vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic
lost+found                   vmlinuz.old
```

Update: Feb 14; I ran sudo apt update/upgrade, and it tried to rebuild some nvidia stuff, but failed. I've truncated this output, since it's very long, if you think I've elided something relevant, LMK, and I can provide more, but this is what looks relevant to my uneducated eyes:

```
        Setting up nvidia-dkms-390 (390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
    update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
    INFO:Enable nvidia
    DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
    DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
    DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
    Removing old nvidia-390.157 DKMS files...
    Deleting module nvidia-390.157 completely from the DKMS tree.
    Loading new nvidia-390.157 DKMS files...
    Building for 6.5.0-17-generic
    Building for architecture x86_64
    Building initial module for 6.5.0-17-generic
    ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-390.0.crash'
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-17-generic (x86_64)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/make.log for more information.
    dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-390 (--configure):
     installed nvidia-dkms-390 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
    Setting up google-chrome-stable (121.0.6167.184-1) ...
    Setting up libgdm1 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.4) ...
    Setting up dns-root-data (2023112702~ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
    
[...]
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     nvidia-dkms-390
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And that error file already exists has this as the first error report (which looks to me like there's a mismatched version of some header or something?)

```
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/common/inc/nv-mm.h:164:45: error: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   164 |                return get_user_pages_remote(tsk, mm, start, nr_pages, flags,
       |                                             ^~~
       |                                             |
       |                                             struct task_struct *
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/common/inc/nv-pgprot.h:17,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/common/inc/nv-linux.h:20:
```

What other info should I gather (please tell me the command I should run)?

Comment: What kernel are you running?  The hwe kernel packages updated to 6.5 in the last two weeks, so gcc-12 needed, but support ended for some old drivers (390?), so you need to drop back to a supported kernel (5.15). Note kernels 5.19 and 6.2 are no longer supported.

Comment: You mention a release (22.04) but weren't specific as to what product (Server? Desktop? or *flavor* as they have different kernel stack defaults which are set by your install media). You also mention *recent update* but what is recent to you?  I upgrade my system daily, so two weeks ago (switch of HWE kernel from 6.2 to 6.5 isn't recent) let alone not giving details as to what 22.04 you're actually using (kernel stack choice exists for LTS releases since 12.04  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: You can try different versions of the Nvidia driver and see if you can fine one without this problem

Comment: The quick answers I can provide right away are that this is desktop, installed out of the box with the 22.04.3 distro, not messed with. "Recent"update between successful presentation a week ago and failure yesterday. If you can hint as to what commands to run to get the specific answers, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Also, I've no idea what a "flavor" is (help!?), and there are only two Nvidia drivers offered, the other is not marked "recommended", but I'll try it, and the Nouveau one too.

Comment: Flavor = {normal Ubuntu GNOME, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu server, ...}

Comment: Ah, well, as best I know "normal Ubuntu", but again, I'm not sure how I would determine that beyond "I downloaded the desktop install, and haven't messed with it".

And, kernel version is 6.5.0-17-generic

Comment: I attempted to change the video driver, but got errors, added to main post.

Comment: Just to clear things up (add to original post):  Do you have /bin/gcc-12 on your system? (Within last week, it should be installed even with an old 22.04.1 ISO). Did the nvidia.ko 390 modules get built with the gcc-12? (To look: strings /lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko |grep gcc ). Is the 5.15 /lib/modules dir still present? Does it contain an nvidia.ko from gcc-11?

Comment: Thanks for the specifics @ubfan1 - I've added what I hope are the relevant bits of into to the original post. Briefly, I think the answers are yes, there's gcc-12, no because..., no there is no nvidia.ko for 6.5.0-17.

I've never (knowingly) compiled any kernel modules for this install, nor have I made any choices other than accepting what the default installation provided.

Comment: An alarming number of /lib/module directories for old kernels.  I hope the old ones are mostly empty, and you don't actually have the kernels in /boot!  How much free space on your / (/boot?)? Keep the (non empty) 6.5s, the last 6.2 (since it looks like it has an nvidia.ko), the last 5.15 (since that's the maintained fall-back kernel if your card can't use the 6.5 kernel). purge the rest, then rm their leftover modules dir if still around. The module compile takes place with the install (for the Canonical supplied ones anyway). Check /etc/modules.d for old blacklists of nvidia or nouveau.

Comment: As an admin user, run Software & Updates/ Additional Drivers and if the 390 is not selected, select it. If it is selected, select nouveau, then when finished, select the 390.  You should be left with the nvidia.ko driver under the /lib/modules/6.5... dirs. reboot and see if that has you running under the nvidia driver (instead of the 915 Intel).

Comment: Thatnks @ubfan1, It's using Nvidia 390, and has been all along. However: I can't change it; the attempt to change to nouveau (or anything else) throws that screenfull of errors I screenshotted and pasted in the main post.

There's only one nvidia.ko file anywhere, that's here:

$ sudo find / -name nvidia.ko 2> /dev/null
/usr/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/kernel/nvidia-390/nvidia.ko


I'm not sure where that leaves me.

BTW, the forum is asking me to move this to a private message. Are you up for that?

Comment: I've added more info...

Comment: ubuntuforums.org would be good for this sort of back and forth, and more people will see it than would if put into chat. For your k1100M , The nvidia search page gives 415 or 418 the driver to use, but those aren't listed on my 6.5 kernel system.  Maybe drop back to the generic 5.15 kernels and do the module install.

Comment: Not offered on my system either.
I'll have to investigate how to change to an older kernel. 
And, not sure how to move this to ubuntuforums... 
(off to google kernel changes)